# Get the user information from document from firestore query?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am querying some documents from firestore. how do I get user info from the snapshot object.

The information like the user ID and user name.

Assuming that the user signed in using a social OAuth provider . IF it matters.

```
firebase.firestore().collection('sample').get()
        .then(function(snapshot) {
            console.log('SNAPSHOT', snapshot);
            snapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                console.log(doc.exists);
                console.log(doc);
                console.log(doc.id);
                console.log(doc.metadata);
                console.log(doc.ref);
                console.log(doc.data());
                console.log(doc.ref.path);
                console.log(doc);
            })
        }).catch(console.log);
```

Comment: Firebase does not automatically create documents for signed in users. So if such a document exists, it's because your application created them. If you indeed did create the document elsewhere, edit your question to include either the code that creates the user documents, or a screenshot of a relevant document in the Firestore console.

Comment: The question was on any  document like articles , post , comments etc.. how to get the user who created them.  Should I explicitly add the user ID when I create any document for other collections.

Comment: Firestore does not associate documents with users. If you want to associate the documents with a user, you can either add a field in each document that holds the user, use the UID of the user in/as the document name, or store the documents for a user in a subcollection.

Answer (score 5):

Firestore does not associate documents with users. If you want to associate the documents with a user, you will have to do this in your application code. You can either add a field in each document that holds the user, use the UID of the user in/as the document ID, or store the documents for a user in a subcollection.

If you add a field in each document that holds the user, you can then get all documents associated with that user with:

```
firebase.firestore().collection('sample').where('uid', '=', firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).get()...
```

If you use the UID of the user as the document ID, you can get a user's document with:

```
firebase.firestore().collection('sample').doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)...
```

If you store the documents for a user in a subcollection of a document named after the user, you can get at that collection with:

```
firebase.firestore().collection('sample').doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).collection('documents')...
```

Answer (score 1):

As Frank van Puffelen pointed out your application needs to implement the logic to create user-documents on Firestore/Firebase RTDB.

The work you have to do is:
1.) create a user account in firebase-backend under 'authentication'. You can give any email combined with any password - those are not real google accounts and just used for your app.

2.)Write the Login-Logic, so that you can log in to your app with your previously created account. Look for an onSuccess message from the server to be sure that everything works.

3.) If a user is logged in, you can retrieve an firebaseAuth.currentUser object from your app and get additional metaData, such as a timestamp of last login. Also, you can now retrieve his email and possibly create a unique ID. With this unique key you can now create new user-records with your own individual data. a typical structure would be:

-your app namespace

--users

---test.user@example.com

----displayName: frank

----age: 47

----loves to eat: spaghetto-code

---exampleUser2@test.com

...

--data

...

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to write backend code using Firebase admin SDK. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users

```js
admin.auth().getUser(uid)
  .then(function(userRecord) {
    // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
    console.log('Successfully fetched user data:', userRecord.toJSON());
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Error fetching user data:', error);
  });
```

Comment: If you want to get current user metadata, you can get  them while user logs in. Firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(async user => {
          console.log(user.metadata)